# NodeJS async.series using predefined functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

All the examples I've been able to find using async.series use anonymous, on the fly functions as the asynchronous processes, like so:

```
async.series([
  function(callback){
    // do some stuff ...
    callback(null, 'first');
  },
  function(callback){
    // do some more stuff ...
    callback(null, 'second');
  }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
  // results is now equal to ['first', 'second']
});
```

Is it possible to structure it so that the functions are predefined? This would be very useful so that I could resuse the functions in other async.series, and would also help structure my code and make it more readable.

For instance:

```
function A (callback) {...}
function B (callback) {...}
function C (err, callback) {...}

async.series ([A,B], C);
```

Comment: `async.series` doesn't know or care where  your functions come from.

Comment: Why haven't you just tried it out? Your example *does work*. And in fact there's no reason why it wouldn't, as a function cannot know whether the functions it receives as arguments were created using declarations or expressions - they're just functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do that.

Edit:

> Is it possible to structure it so that the functions are predefined?
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> function A (callback) {...}
> function B (callback) {...}
> function C (err, callback) {...}
>
> async.series ([A,B], C);
> ```

Comment: @MLavoie how do you believe this does not answer the question?

Comment: How? How can you do that? Please expand your answer.

Comment: @ppperry okay, see my edit where I quote the yes or no question.

Comment: A good question contains half of the answer. This question contains the answer. +1

Comment: @zerkms: A good question contains *only* half of the answer. This is not a good question.